# Using SQL Server to achieve the same thing as mongoose in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to create an API for user authentication to access data from SQL Server, however most resources I have found are based on MongoDB, such as this one: [Restful API design with Node.js](https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-design-with-node-js-26ccf66eab09)

I followed the tutorial and can connect to SQL Server by replacing 'mongoose' with 'mssql'.

Now there is a part that I can't figure out how to change it to the equivalent code:

```
// User.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String
});
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User');
```

The code above is using mongoose, but for SQL Server there is nothing like `mssql.model` to use.

How can I achieve the same thing using SQL Server?

Edit: This is the official docs from Mongoose: 
[Mongoose Models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)
I need to achieve the same thing using the mssql package:
[mssql package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So MongoDB and SQL Server are like a lot different from one another. In MongoDB, there are documents and not table inside the databases, that mongoose.model is actually to be able to create a model for your document.

While to achieve the same kind of result (Since two are totally different), you may create a table using the following code:
I am also providing connection method so you can verify that too.

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'YOUR HOST',
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "CREATE TABLE users(name VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(25)";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Table created");
  });
});
```

This will be helpful, to your specific query, although I suggest you to study SQL-server Query Language first and understand How you can create a query on NodeJS.